# Are Maximal Consistent set of formulas unique?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I know that for any consistent set of formulas $\Gamma$, there exists a maximal consistent set of formulas $\Theta$, such that $\Gamma\subseteq\Theta$.  Given this, do we know if $\Theta$ is unique?

Comment: [These](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22maximal+consistent+set+of+formulas%22+AND+%22unique%22+AND+%22math+stack%22+site:math.stackexchange.com&client=ms-android-samsung-ga-rev1&sxsrf=ALeKk023wAntrZwgbfiCqUrKT_7BkO3TzA:1592852354203&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_xIG2jZbqAhUSmIsKHW05BIwQrQIoAjAAegQIAhAL&cshid=1592852428302&biw=1261&bih=2372&dpr=2.63) are some related questions.

Answer (score 3):

No, having a unique maximal consistent extension is equivalent to a theory being complete and consistent. So any incomplete consistent theory (e.g. PA) has more than one maximal consistent extension.

If $T$ is consistent and incomplete, and $\varphi$ is undecidable in $T,$ then $T\cup\{\varphi\}$ and $T\cup \{\lnot \varphi\}$ are both consistent, so have (necessarily different) maximal consistent extensions which are both maximal consistent extensions of $T$.