One way to obtain maximally consistent set
Given a consistent set of formulas is there only one way to extend this to a maximally consistent set?
Context: we are at propositional logic only.
I guess that during the process of extende, instead of choice some $\alpha_i$, we coud choice $\neg\alpha_i$. However, I know that $\neg\alpha_i$ isn't a atomic proposition, but, if I can't do this, what is the reason?
Thanks in advance

Answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3730537/are-maximal-consistent-set-of-formulas-unique

@TankutBeygu this doesn't answer cause it is about first order logic
